# NSUserDefaults in logic test

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, nsuserdefaults

Does NSUserDefaults work in logic tests or only in/on simulator/hardware?

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to validate in unit tests that you can set and retrieve values from NSUserDefaults, if that's what you mean.